# Do I need connect-multiparty for express after I have setup body-parser in the root of my application?

Tags: javascript, node.js

so in my application's root, I aleady setup body-parser to work with express and passport. Do I still need to use connect-multiparty and does this add any functionality or just bloats up my runtime.

Answer (score 0):

the body-parser module does not handle multipart bodies. connect-multiparty is for parsing multipart data (including file uploads) from forms. So if thats what you want then yes you still need it. I wouldnt use connect-multiparty though. The creator even says this about the module

> I actually recommend against using this module. It's cleaner to use the multiparty API directly.

I usually use busboy https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy